# Similar use of 'of' as below

Tags: grammar

Could you guys give me another examples which share the same meaning as below?

1. The same could be said 'of' other cases.
2. God will ask some hard things of you.

Thank you

Comment: hi, welcome to ELL! This is not the right place to get your homework done, so please edit you question by adding some more details / information

Comment: *He thinks well of you, How kind of you!, The rest of you can go, He made a fool of you,...*

Answer (score 1):

"Of" often does not have a meaning of its own, but forms part of a phrase. Your two examples exemplify two different phrases.

In the first one, *say of*, or *be said of* (passive), *of* means "about". It's somewhat literary: in ordinary speech you'd say "They say he ..." or "They call him ..." rather than "It's said of him that ..."

*To ask something of somebody* is a rather literary way of saying "to expect or require that the person does or gives the something", with the implication that the something is difficult or costly. They may or may not be literally "asking".
In more ordinary speech, we would say "ask somebody for something" or "ask somebody to do something", and not use "of" at all.